# How can I merge 3 distinct Sqls by the same grouping but different columns (Sql Server Stored Procedure)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 distinct queries in a Stored Procedure in Sql Server. I need to merge the results grouping by 
**"Date, Team, Account"**, and having the columns:

```
(Query1.NumberUnits + Query2.NumberUnits) AS TotalUnits,
(Query2.NumberCartons) AS TotalCartons,
(Query3.TotalPallets) AS TotalPallets
```

> My Sqls are a bit complex so I couldn't post here to don't make it too
>   complicated, but I need some command like **Merge** or **Union all** or even
>   **temporary tables**, but I don't know how to use in this case.

**Query 1**

```
╔═══════════╦════════╦═══════════╦════════════════╦═════════════╗
║   Date    ║ TeamId ║ AccountId ║ TransactionQty ║ NumberUnits ║
╠═══════════╬════════╬═══════════╬════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 8/12/2014 ║      4 ║      1989 ║              4 ║           4 ║
╚═══════════╩════════╩═══════════╩════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

**Query 2**

```
╔═══════════╦════════╦═══════════╦════════════════╦═══════════════╦═════════════╗
║   Date    ║ TeamId ║ AccountId ║ TransactionQty ║ NumberCartons ║ NumberUnits ║
╠═══════════╬════════╬═══════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 8/12/2014 ║      4 ║      1989 ║              6 ║             6 ║           1 ║
╚═══════════╩════════╩═══════════╩════════════════╩═══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

**Query 3**

```
╔═══════════╦════════╦═══════════╦══════════════╗
║   Date    ║ TeamId ║ AccountId ║ TotalPallets ║
╠═══════════╬════════╬═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ 8/12/2014 ║      5 ║      2000 ║            2 ║
║ 9/12/2014 ║      4 ║      1989 ║            1 ║
╚═══════════╩════════╩═══════════╩══════════════╝
```

**Query Result**

```
╔═══════════╦════════╦═══════════╦════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╗
║   Date    ║ TeamId ║ AccountId ║ TotalUnits ║ TotalCartons ║ TotalPallets ║
╠═══════════╬════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 8/12/2014 ║      4 ║      1989 ║          5 ║            6 ║            0 ║
║ 8/12/2014 ║      5 ║      2000 ║          0 ║            0 ║            2 ║
║ 9/12/2014 ║      4 ║      1989 ║          0 ║            0 ║            1 ║
╚═══════════╩════════╩═══════════╩════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with either `full outer join` or with `union all` and `group by`.  Here is the `union all` method:

```
with q1 as (<query1>),
     q2 as (<query2>),
     q3 as (<query3>)
select date, TeamId, AccountId,
       sum(NumberUnits) as TotalUnits,
       sum(NumberCartons) as TotalCartons,
       sum(TotalPallets) as TotalPallets
from ((select date, TeamId, AccountId, NumberUnits, 0 as NumberCartons, 0 as TotalPallets
       from q1 
      ) union all
      (select date, TeamId, AccountId, NumberUnits, NumberCartons, 0 as TotalPallets
       from q2 
      ) union all
      (select date, TeamId, AccountId, 0 as NumberUnits, 0 as NumberCartons, TotalPallets
       from q3 
      )
     ) qqq
group by date, TeamId, AccountId
order by date, TeamId, AccountId;
```

Comment: can I call three other stored procedures replacing <query1>, <query2>, <query3> for "exec sp_query1",2,3 ?

Comment: @RogerOliveira . . . I'm not sure what you mean.  Your query describes the these as "queries" not "stored procedures". There are way to get results from a stored procedure into a table, but I would recommend doing the work as queries and not stored procedures.

Comment: Yes, I will use queries instead, thanks. @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 2):

**Create table**

```
DECLARE @q1 TABLE ([Date] DATE, TeamId INT, AccountId INT, TransactionQty INT, NumberUnits INT)
DECLARE @q2 TABLE ([Date] DATE, TeamId INT, AccountId INT, TransactionQty INT, NumberCartons INT, NumberUnits INT)
DECLARE @q3 TABLE ([Date] DATE, TeamId INT, AccountId INT, TotalPallets INT)
```

**Sample data**

```
INSERT INTO @q1 VALUES ('8/12/2014', 4, 1989, 4, 4)
INSERT INTO @q2 VALUES ('8/12/2014', 4, 1989, 6, 6, 1)
INSERT INTO @q3 VALUES ('8/12/2014', 5, 2000, 2)
                       ,('9/12/2014', 4, 1989, 1)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT  [Date], TeamId, AccountId,
        ISNULL(SUM(NumberUnits), 0) AS TotalUnits,
        ISNULL(SUM(NumberCartons), 0),
        ISNULL(SUM(TotalPallets), 0)
FROM (
    SELECT [Date], TeamId, AccountId, NULL AS NumberCartons, NumberUnits, NULL AS TotalPallets FROM @q1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [Date], TeamId, AccountId, NumberCartons, NumberUnits, NULL FROM @q2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [Date], TeamId, AccountId, NULL, NULL, TotalPallets FROM @q3
    ) AS t
GROUP BY [Date], TeamId, AccountId
```

Comment: That's great, is there any other way to do this merge with union all? As my final SP will have 7 queries, and to be repeating NULL, NULL,NULL is not very nice in my code, if this is the only way, it is okay.